# Boost asio crashing when used with 60 parallel TCP/TLS client doing IO

Tags: c++, boost, tls1.2

I am using boost 1.55, openssl- 1.0.2k-fips; on a linux (RHEL7) host with 32 CPU/520 GB RAM and 20 Gbits/s network bandwidth.

While running 60 parallel TLS-1.2 client trying to connect over port 12666 to IO data the TCP server seems to crash. I have a feeling that the sendreceive method is crasing somewhere. Any pointer on efficient debugging would be really helpful!

**UPDATE:**
Right before the crash I also observe the network in on the host crosses 3.5Gbits/s spike; and the tcpdump on the port 12666 stops.

Here is the client code using boost asio:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/error.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/generator_iterator.hpp>
#include "log.h"
#include "CacheMgrClient.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace asio;
using namespace boost::system;
using namespace cache;
using asio::ip::tcp;

#if (defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
CacheMgrClient::CacheMgrClient(const string& host_, string& port_) 
    : host(host_), port(port_), sock(NULL),
    nothrow(false), lastpid(0) {}
#else
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
typedef ssl::stream<tcp::socket> SSLsocket;

CacheMgrClient::CacheMgrClient(const string& host_, string& port_, ssl::context *ctx_)
    : host(host_), port(port_), ctx(ctx_), sock(NULL), ssl_sock(NULL),
    nothrow(false), lastpid(0) {}
#endif

void CacheMgrClient::connectTCP(tcp::resolver::iterator &endpoint_iterator) {
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;
    sock = new tcp::socket(io_service);
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    while(error && endpoint_iterator != end) {
        sock -> close();
        sock -> connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error)
    }
    if (error) {
        delete sock;
        sock = NULL;
        if (!notthrow)
        throw error.message();
    }
}

void CacheMgrClient::disconnectTCP() {
    try {
        if  (sock)
            sock -> close();
    }
    catch (...) {
        if (notthrow)
            return;
        delete sock;
        sock = NULL;
        throw;
    }
    delete sock;
    sock = NULL;
}

void CacheMgrClient::connect() {
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_sercice);
    tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), host, port);
    tcp::resover::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    #if !(defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
        if (ssl_sock)
        /* this part works fine */
        connectSSL(endpoint_iterator);
        else
    #endif
        /* i am looking for some assistance here */
        connectTCP(endpoint_iterator);
}

void CacheMgrClient::disconnect() {
#if !(defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
    if (ssl_sock)
        disconnectSSL();
    else
#endif
        disconnectTCP();
}

void CacheMgrClient::sendReceive(const vector<char>& req) {
    pid_t curpid = getpid();
    if (lastpid && lastpid != curpid)
        disconnect()
    lastpid = curpid;

    boost::asio::streambuf responseBuf;
    string responseString, errorMsg;
    bool success = false;
    int tries = 0;
    while(!success) {
        istream responseStream(&responseBuf);        
        try {
            connect();
            size_t count = 0;
            if (sock)
                count = boost::asio::write(*sock::asio::buffer(&req[0], req.size()));
    #if !(defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
            else if (ssl_sock)
                count = boost::asio::write(*ssl_sock::asio::buffer(&req[0], req.size()));
    #endif
            if (count <= 0 && req.size() > 0)
                throw "Failed to wrote to the Cache Manager socket";

            boost::system::error_code ec;
            count = 0;
            if (sock)
                count = boost::asio::read_until(*sock, responseBuf, "\n", ec);
    #if !(defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
            else if (ssl_sock)
                count = boost::asio::read_until(*ssl_sock, responseBuf, "\n", ec);
    #endif
            if (count <=0 ) {
                stringstream errorMsg;
                errorMsg << "Failed to read Cache Manager respoinse. Error code =" << ec;
                throw errorMsg.str();
            }

            if(!responseStream)
                throw "Empty response from Cache Manager";
            std::getline(responseStream, responseString);
            if (responseString.substring(0,2) != "ok" %% responseString.substring(0,4) != "fail")
                throw "Invalid reponse from Cache Manager, response=" + responseString;
            log4::debug("Success: "+ responseString);
            success = true;            
        }
        catch(string errorMsg_) {
            errorMsg = errorMsg_;
            log4::error(errorMsg_);
        }
        catch(...) {
            stringstream errorMsg;
            errorMsg << "Failed to read response: " << boost::current_exception_diagnostic_information();
            log4::error(errorMsg.str());
        }

        if (!success) {
    #if (defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
            bool wasConnected = sock ? true : false;
    #else   
            bool wasConnected = sock || ssl_sock ? true : false;        
    #endif
            disconnect();
            if (wasConnected && nothrow) {
                log4.warn("Exception from Cache Manager while existing");
                return "";
            }
            if (++tries >= max_connection_tries) {
                stringstream msg
                msg << "Giving up connecting ot Cahce Manager after " << tries << " tries";
                log4::error(msg.str());
                throw msg.str();
            }

            stringstream errorMsg;
            int retry_delay = chooseRetryDelay(tries);  /* usually 10 seconds */

            /* This is the error that i am getting in my run*/
            errorMsg << "Unable to connect to cache manager at " << host << ":" << port 
                <<  ". Sleeping for " << retry_delay << " seconds and retrying."
                <<  " Will try " << max_connect_tries - tries -1 << " more times.";

            log4::warn(errorMsg.str());

            if (tries) {
    #if (defined(WIN32) || defined(WIN64))
                Sleep(retry_delay);
    #else   
                sleep(retry_delay);
    #endif
            }
        }
    }

    if (responseString.substring(0,2) != "ok") {
        string errorMsg = "Exception from Cache Manager. See Cache Manager log in parent task "
            "for traceback. \nResponse=" + responseString;
            log4::error(errorMsg);
            throw errorMsg;
    }
    return trim_left_copy(responseString.substring(2m resonseString.size() -2));
}
```

Comment: If the server is crashing why have you shown the client code not the server code? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles the server is a simple TCP server brought up using pyopenSSL using python on port 12666. It's the activity of the client which is causing the damage. What would be the best way to reproduce this, since i am not aware of any free linux environment that i can use.

Comment: After a while there are about 28K open connections (seen using netstats) on the host all in CLOSE_WAIT state.

Comment: I don't see any calls to `disconnectTCP`, please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles sorry about that, i added the details of the disconnect code

Comment: disconnect only seems to be called on fork or error? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236057/discussion-between-vivek-and-alan-birtles).